# Why doesn't <table mat-table> apply flexbox properties?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-material-table

In my template I have,

```html
...
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
...
```

In my template style I have

```css
...
.mat-column-name {
  color: red;
  // flex: 0 1 200px !important; // not getting applied
  max-width: 200px;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
...
```

I wanted to control column width. But when using `flex` property in `mat-column-name`, it doesn't get applied. As a workaround I am using `max-width`. It kind of works, but I don't understand how `max-width` is getting used to make it responsive

Edit:
Working code [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/customizing-mat-columns)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `<mat-table ...` instead of `<table mat-table...` for flexbox to kick in

I was using

```html
<table mat-table ...
...
<ng-container ...
    <th ..
    <td ..
...
```

Instead I need to change to

```html
<mat-table ...
<ng-container ...
    <mat-header-cell ...
    <mat-cell ...
...
```

Your `flex: 0 1 200px;` CSS property will become active as `mat-row`'s display type is `flex` now.

See https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-display-flex